# Drupal, Ubercart: Extended price for products in the templat?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm modifying the invoice template of my Ubercart shop.

There is a missing parameter I need (Please see the image): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/extendedPrice.png

The Extended Price is not correct. I need to multiply the unit price for the units. I was wondering how can I retrieve it (i.e. The unit price is uc_price($price_info, $context) ).

I could compute it multiplying units number and price in the template, but I would prefer to not do it, if possible, since I have also the currency symbol.. and I should parse the data.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the quantity in the call to `uc_price`. If unit price is 20 and quantity is 2,

```
$price_info = array('price' => 20, 'qty' => 2);
uc_price($price_info, $context);
```